# 3D Plotting with Piecewise function

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I'm trying to plot the following function:

$f(x,y)=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 (x+y) & (x,y) \in T \\ 
 (x+y)^2 & (x,y) \notin  T
\end{matrix}\right.$

where  $T= \{ y\leq -x+1, x\geq 0, y\geq 0 \}$

I'm trying without success something like:

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{x + y, {y <= -x + 1, x>=0, y>=0}}, {(x + y)^2, y > -x + 1}}, 
  0], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

I don't know if the `Piecewise` function supports multiple conditions like ${y \le -x + 1, x \ge 0, y \ge 0}$ for some piece.

Comment: You need to combine the conditions with `And` instead of making a list. `Piecewise[{{x + y, y <= -x + 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0}, {(x + y)^2, True}}]` will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
p1 = Plot3D[(x + y), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y <= -x + 1 && y >= 0 && x >= 0]];

p2 = Plot3D[(x + y)^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= y + x || y + x <= 0 || y <=  0 || x <=  0]];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: plot]

You can also use `UnitStep` to define your region and to generate one function.

Answer (score 4):

You can do with `Piecewise`:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{x + y, y <= -x + 1 && x >= 0 && y    >= 0}, {(x + y)^2, True}}]
plt = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 64}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {(#1 + #2 &), #1 &, #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1.}, {0}, {0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]